# How to create a diagonal matrix with blocks in the diagonal with each block a different matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create a block diagonal matrix that looks like:

```
M

A1 0  0  0   0
0 A2  0  0   0 
0  0 A3  0   0 
0  0  0 A4   0 
0  0  0  0  A5
```

with each 0 being a matrix of zeros and each of the A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 matrices being a square matrix, each with the same dimensions, but with different entries.

If I have each of the matrices A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 are known to me, if there a way to generate such a large block diagonal matrix without resorting to loops?

I am hoping to find a solution that can work for any number of matrices, hopefully not just 5. Thanks!

Comment: Place the matrices in a `list` and do `bdiag` i.e. `library(Matrix); bdiag(mget(paste0('A', 1:5)))`

Comment: for the particular case where all As are identical, `kronecker(diag(5), matrix(1:9,3,3))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `bdiag` from `Matrix` after placing the matrices in a `list` to get a `sparseMatrix`.

```
library(Matrix)
sM <- bdiag(mget(paste0("A", 1:5)))
sM
# 10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

# [1,] 1 3 . .  .  .  .  .  .  .
# [2,] 2 4 . .  .  .  .  .  .  .
# [3,] . . 5 7  .  .  .  .  .  .
# [4,] . . 6 8  .  .  .  .  .  .
# [5,] . . . .  9 11  .  .  .  .
# [6,] . . . . 10 12  .  .  .  .
# [7,] . . . .  .  . 13 15  .  .
# [8,] . . . .  .  . 14 16  .  .
# [9,] . . . .  .  .  .  . 17 19
#[10,] . . . .  .  .  .  . 18 20
```

If needed, the `sparseMatrix` can be converted to a `matrix`

```
as.matrix(sM)
```

#### data

```
A1 <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
A2 <- matrix(5:8, 2, 2)
A3 <- matrix(9:12, 2, 2)
A4 <- matrix(13:16, 2, 2)
A5 <- matrix(17:20, 2, 2)
```